# Why does this not set the main window's background to a different image than that of the background of the textboxes?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Packages:
Python 3.115 with PyQt5

Issue:
While I have very little experience with this package (please expand if complicated; but mostly I seem to have it working for what I want it to do) I continue to have an issue properly setting the background of the app's main window.

In the code below, I am trying to utilize **main_window_background** to set the image of that main window while using **self.background_image** to set the image behind the textboxes.

Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QScrollBar, QFrame
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QBrush, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class CustomWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.background_image = QPixmap("../../Cpp/textbox_bg.png")  #background image for text entries

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.background_image)
        super().paintEvent(event)

class CustomWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Custom Window")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 700)

        # Set the background image for the main window
        main_window_background = QPixmap("../../Cpp/parchment_textbox_bg.png")  #main window background image
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Window, QBrush(main_window_background))
        self.setPalette(palette)

        central_widget = CustomWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        # Create a container for the text entry widgets
        text_entry_container = QFrame()
        text_entry_container.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;")
        layout.addWidget(text_entry_container)

        text_entry_layout = QVBoxLayout(text_entry_container)

        # Create and add the first QTextEdit widget with a scrollbar
        text_edit1 = QTextEdit(self)
        text_edit1.setGeometry(0, 0, 150, 125)
        text_edit1.setMaximumSize(150, 125)  # Maintain size
        text_edit1.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        text_entry_layout.addWidget(text_edit1)

        scrollbar1 = QScrollBar(Qt.Vertical, self)
        text_entry_layout.addWidget(scrollbar1)
        text_edit1.setVerticalScrollBar(scrollbar1)

        # Create and add the second QTextEdit widget with a scrollbar
        text_edit2 = QTextEdit(self)
        text_edit2.setGeometry(0, 0, 150, 125)
        text_edit2.setMaximumSize(150, 125)  # Maintain size
        text_edit2.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        text_entry_layout.addWidget(text_edit2)

        scrollbar2 = QScrollBar(Qt.Vertical, self)
        text_entry_layout.addWidget(scrollbar2)
        text_edit2.setVerticalScrollBar(scrollbar2)

        # Create and add the third QTextEdit widget with a scrollbar
        text_edit3 = QTextEdit(self)
        text_edit3.setGeometry(0, 0, 150, 125)
        text_edit3.setMaximumSize(150, 125)  # Maintain size
        text_edit3.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        text_entry_layout.addWidget(text_edit3)

        scrollbar3 = QScrollBar(Qt.Vertical, self)
        text_entry_layout.addWidget(scrollbar3)
        text_edit3.setVerticalScrollBar(scrollbar3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = CustomWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I expected to see the main window in the darker 'parchment' image referenced by **main_window_background**, but instead both the main window's background and the textboxes appear to use the lighter image referenced by **self.background_image**.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  I have confirmed path; confirmed images; if I swap the two image references, as expected (but also as unwanted) it all appears in the darker background, rather than the light.  I can't find the solution.

Comment: The central widget covers the whole main window area (except for the space used by QMainWindow elements such as menu bar, status bar, etc.) so you see the background used in `paintEvent()` because that's all its occupied space. And you also see it for the textboxes because you're using a generic properties in the QSS: style sheets are propagated to all children, and unless you use proper [selector types](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) all those properties are set for them. In this case, all those QTextEdits have a transparent background. Remove that line completely.

Comment: Also note that: 1. it makes no sense to add a scroll bar to the layout and then also call `setVerticalScrollBar()`; 2. it's useless to set a geometry of a widget that is being added to a layout; 3. if the widget is going to be opaque (and/or is being shown on an opaque parent) setting the `WA_NoSystemBackground` attribute is pointless.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).